# React Native reusable components with Yarn workspace

Tags: reactjs, react-native, yarnpkg, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I want to make monorepo with multiple react native apps and shared packages. I had to add nohoist for every RN app and to configure Metro to watch shared code like:

```
watchFolders: [
  path.resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules/@shared/.....'),
  path.resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules'),
],
```

I can reuse functions and constants, but when I try to import shared component (button for example), I cannot use it like `<Button />` and I receive error related to useState etc. I tried to compile that shared component with typescript, added babel, tried preconstruct but nothing worked. When I console log what I imported, i see function, when i call it i see jsx element and typeof that element is object.

Any advice?

Comment: Try Nx, it supports react-native out the box

Comment: @Cloud_Ratha Thanks for your reply. NX supports integrated monorepo, but in this case I want package-based monorepo, each workspaces to have its own package.json and node modules

Comment: Use lerna then :) Lerna supports nx too